# Confirm git merge strategy

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I've looked at a bunch of documentation on stack and the internet about best practices for `merging an existing directory` `into an existing git repository`.

From what i have seen, the best strategy for me to get the existing directory into the git repository is:

- `cd ~/path/to/existing/directory`
- execute command `git init`
- execute commands `git add . && git commit -m'pushing existing directory into repo'`
- execute command `git remote add origin https|ssh:path/to/the/repository.git`
- execute command `git pull origin master`
- execute command `git push origin master`

and now at this point i should have the existing directory merged into the git repository with the existing directory overwrites taking precedence and a link to the git repo. what about conflicts from the existing directory and the repo files?

can someone confirm this is the correct strategy?

if not, my next strategy is:

- mv existingdirectory to existingdirectorybak
- clone git repo into separatedirectory
- cp existingdirectorybak to cloned directory
- push changes
- mv cloned directory into existingdirectory

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but here's what I would do:

1. In your existing repository folder create a new branch: `git checkout -b branchX`
2. Copy the existing directory onto your git directory
3. `git add --all`
4. `git commit -am 'New files! Yeah.'`